# Incorrect parse with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm parse site http://animecalendar.net with Jsoup. Аll is well parsed fine, but i have one problem. I get a mixed list of urls, but they are parsed correctly (see logs)

Code:

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<Order> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        listItems.clear();
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        String dates = null;
                    String url = null;

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

            Elements main = doc.select("div.day");
            for (Element m : main) {
                titles = m.select("div.tooltip");
                for (Element tts : titles) {

                    title = tts.select("td.tooltip_title h4").text();
                    time = tts.select("td.tooltip_info h4").text();
                    img = tts.select("td.tooltip_desc img[src]");

                    Order o = new Order();
                    o.setLink(URL + img.attr("src"));
                    o.setTextName(title);
                    o.setTextTime(time);
                    o.setTextDate(dates);
                    o.setDetailsUrl(URL + url);  // incorrect (mixed) displayed urls list in device
                    listItems.add(o);
                }

                Elements date = m.select("h2");                 
                for (Element m1 : date) {
                    dates = m1.select("a").attr("href");                        
                }

                Elements links = m.select("h3");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    url = link.select("a").attr("href");  // parse urls from site
                         System.out.println(url);  // in LogCat displayed correct urls list
                }                   
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listItems;
    }
```

LogCat:

```
01-21 12:55:55.429: I/System.out(8036): /show/596/Cardfight%21%21_Vanguard%3A_Asia_Circuit_Hen
01-21 12:55:55.429: I/System.out(8036): /show/583/Inazuma_Eleven_GO_2%3A_Chrono_Stone
01-21 12:55:55.445: I/System.out(8036): /show/671/Ai_Mai_Mi_
01-21 12:55:55.445: I/System.out(8036): /show/697/Mangirl%21
etc...
```

As a result, I get a mixed list of urls.
Screen:
[image]

How to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What correct result do you want?

Comment: Hi. Name of anime and a link to this anime does not match. When I click to forward image I have to go to the page of this anime. Accessibly? My English so bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved like this

```
Elements epBox = doc.select("div.ep_box h3");
            int urlcount = 0;
            for (Element ep : epBox) {
                url = ep.select("a").attr("href");

                if (urlcount < listItems.size()) {
                    Order o = (Order) listItems.get(urlcount);
                    o.setDetailsUrl(URL + url);
                    newarraylist.add(o);
                }
                urlcount++;
            }
```